# Strategy for accessing an application-wide setting on the client in a .NET Core web app

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are in the process of re-writing one of our applications using ASP.NET Core.  The architecture we're trying for has a Web API running on a different URL from the presentation.  The root URL for this API will change in different environments, of course, so I'm trying to figure out how I can set up configuration and access to the Web API root URL in the JavaScript that requires it for retrieving data.  For example, say I have an AJAX call to fetch some data from the API:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://this.url.will.change/api/whatever",  //this will change!
    success: function(response) {
        //load the items
    }
});
```

I've set up `appsettings.json` files for various build/deploy scenarios and have them reading and injecting nicely, so I can store the URL there.

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
             "ConnectionString": "whatever"
        }
    }, 
    "AppSettings": {
        "ApiRootUrl": "http://apiroot/api/"
    }
}
```

I considered writing a `UrlHelper` extension to provide the Web API root, but I don't think there's a way to inject the `IOptions` object into a static extension method.  So, my question is really this: How can I make a configuration setting globally available in my CSHTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Startup.cs like below

```
public class Startup {
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv) {
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
    }
}
```

Then on your controller you can inject configuration like this

```
public class ConfigurationController : Controller {
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot config;

    public ConfigurationController (IConfigurationRoot config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public string Test() {
        return config.Get<string>("AppSettings:ApiRootUrl");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've used to create a special configuration controller which was responsible for creating a dynamic javascript file from selected configurations settings. You can inject IOptions to the controller. Then from the options you can construct a new custom configuration object which will hold only the properties you want to expose (you probably don't want to expose anything like connection string to your db).
Use a json library (like json.net) to serialize this custom configuration object to a JSON string and create file content out of it like

```
string fileContent = "var globalConf =" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configObject);
```

Convert the string to array of bytes and return it as `FileContentResult`.
We were also setting some cache headers so the browser didn't hit the controller each time and used cache.

Of course you need to setup routing o the call to specific URL will hit your controller and return the javascript file you have dynamically created. You can reference it on a website using usual script tag.

As for the server side rendering you can always include IOptions in the model (or create a new model which will wrap both options and the original model)